# nftable access to LXD container

Tags: networking, linux-networking, nat, ubuntu-18.04, nftables

My plan is to provide a nextcloud container and a ONLYOFFICE container.

- I have a ubuntu LTS server system running.
- There are several LXD container running.
- I can access all container with browser via their difined ports; configured by nftables
- Container have access to internet, provided by host connection

But...

- suddenly the container can't curl each other the host IP. -> Nextcloud can't access ONLYOFFICE so this is not working.
- Even the Host can't curl to the defined ports. :-(

I think my problem is in my nftables config:

```
table ip my_nat {
  chain my_prerouting {
    type nat hook prerouting priority -100;
    tcp dport{ http, https } dnat 192.168.22.3
    tcp dport{ 8888} dnat 192.168.22.6:80
    tcp dport{ 8889} dnat 192.168.22.6:443
  }

  chain my_postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority 0; policy accept;
        oifname "eno1" masquerade
 }
}
```

eno1 is the host port
lxdbr0 is the bridge port to all container - 192.168.22.0/24

Comment: I don't think that nftables is supported with LXD. See https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/4029.

Comment: After reading through, it seems supported and fixed: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/6223
I think the problem maybe a missing entry for postrouting?!?

Comment: As I read it, it is intended to be part of release 3.22. But that is not released yet. https://github.com/lxc/lxd/milestone/91?closed=1

Comment: It seems not related to LXD even a curl to localhost(on the mainhost) doesn't work:
'''Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused'''

Comment: To expose a port for locally executed programs you have to hook into *output*. *prerouting* will not work for that. But that is tricky. See my net namespace answer here: https://serverfault.com/a/1002882/188737